# Django Modelform Instance Update with Clean_field() method of modelform field in form.py

Tags: python, django

I want to Update some value of a Book instance in Django from. I have put clean_field() methods in forms.py. So, everytime I update the value in a form it validates the clean_field and raises a validationError for those two fields. I want to bypass that while I update the object's some parameter like bookPrice or publicationDate. so, I can update that value without getting an error on existing fields. I have put clean_field() for bookname,bookisbn.

**views.py**

```
def updateBook(request, key_id):
    book = Book.objects.get(bookIsbn__exact=key_id)

    # date format 2/21/2020
    print(request.method)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BookUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=book)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('bookList')
        else:
            print(form.errors.as_data())
    form = BookUploadForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=book)
    template = 'storeApp-Templates/bookUpdate.html'
    context = {'book': book, 'form': form}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

**form.py**

```
class BookUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = "__all__"
        widgets = {
            'bookName': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-controls'}),
            'bookPrice': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-controls'}),
            'bookAuthor': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-controls'}),
            'bookIsbn': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-controls'}),
            'bookPublicationDate': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-controls'}),

        }

    bookPublicationDate = forms.DateField(widget=AdminDateWidget())

    # this methods will generate error for book update as well as new book Upload
    def clean_bookName(self, *args, **kwargs):
        bookname = self.cleaned_data.get('bookName')
        qs = Book.objects.filter(bookName__exact=bookname)
        if qs.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("This BookName has already been used.")
        return bookname

    def clean_bookIsbn(self, *args, **kwargs):
        bookisbn = self.cleaned_data.get('bookIsbn')
        qs = Book.objects.filter(bookIsbn__exact=bookisbn)
        if qs.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("This ISBN has already been used. Please Use a new ISBN.")
        if len(bookisbn) != 11 and len(bookisbn) != 13:
            raise forms.ValidationError("ISBN length has to be 11 or 13.")
        return bookisbn
```

So, because of this clean_field() i cant update any value in a book instance any object I try to update it raises a validationError of **This BookName has already been used** && **This ISBN has already been used. Please Use a new ISBN.** Because of that clean_field() validation in form.py.

Comment: If you pass `unique=True` to the `Book.bookName` and `Book.bookIsbn` model fields then you will not have to manually perform uniqueness validation as the ModelForm will do it for you

Comment: If you want to do the uniqueness validation yourself you should exclude the current instance you are editing: `Book.objects.filter(bookName__exact=bookname).exclude(pk=self.instance.pk)`

Comment: Will try your solution of adding uniqueness to models field in models.py and will revert you back.

Comment: @IainShelvington Thanks for the help. Used that exclude() methods.